# Wordpress Live to MAMP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having trouble moving a Wordpress installation from my live server to MAMP. So far I have

- Copied all the files from the live server to a directory on my local machine (htdocs)
- Backed up the database from PHPMyAdmin
- Replaced http://www.mysite.com with (http://)localhost:8888/mysite/
- Replaced /var/www/vhosts/mysite/httpdocs/ with /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/

What I see is the homepage working with all the menus and posts there and the admin seems fine however when I click a menu item I get an error message saying:

> The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

I cannot get past the homepage. Can anyone help? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try regenerating the .htaccess file at /wp-admin/options-permalink.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you've not updated your .htaccess file. You'll need to change your RewriteRules.

This is (probably) because your site was originally on the root of your webserver and now it's in a subdirectory within your MAMP.

Comment: Thanks Scott spot on! I appreciate your help